# WP/PHP, how to use regex to get a filename

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Working on a Wordpress project with a CPT "audio-book", on the each audio-book post page in the front-end view, it has a mp3 player.

Because there are so many audio files, instead of attaching each audio to its belonging post from the admin, I am wondering how to make a php function that can automatically recognize the right filename and making it available to the front-end.

All the audio files are named under the same rules:

```
{Category#}-{Story#}-{VoiceOverArtist}_{otherText}.mp3
```

C{#}-S{#}-{NAME}_{other_text}.mp3
Where the "other_text" part is optional

Here's what the audio filenames are like:

[AudioFolder]

- C1-S1-Jason_slow.mp3
- C1-S25-Jenny_revision2.mp3
- C2-S43-Jason.mp3
- C4-S99-Thomas_with_background_music.mp3

In the single audio CPT template,
I would like a php function "get_audio_file($category, $story_id)".

Ideally:

```
<?= get_audio_file("C1", "S25"); ?>
```

would output "C1-S25-Jenny_revision2.mp3", and

```
<?= get_audio_file("C4", "S99"); ?>
```

would output "C4-S99-Thomas_with_background_music.mp3"

I would also like the function to recognize the voice over artist name, so I can later use a array to cross reference it, and display pink or blue color in the audio post page to indicate the gender of the voice artist.

Here is my current effort with my limited PHP knowledge:

```
    function get_audio_file($category, $story_id) {
    
    // Define the root folder of the audio files 
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $dir = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/story/audio';
    

    // Saw this from other question.. not sure how to implement it with regular expression 
    $files = glob($dir.'/*.mp3');


    $artist = {artist_name}; //this part I have no clue how to grab the artist name into the variable.

    // Getting the filename prefix, eg: C1-S5-{artist}-{suffix}
    // suffix is optional, might not exist
    $filename_prefix = $category . "-" . $story_id;

    if ( !empty( $suffix ) {
      $filename = $filename_prefix . "-" . $artist . "_" . $suffix;
    } else {
      $filename = $filename_prefix . "-" . $artist;
    }

    // Put the voice artist name into gender-based array
    $female_artist = array("Jenny", "Sabrina"...);
    $male_artist = array("Jason", "Tom", "Thomas"...);
    
    
    // This determine the gender of the voice artist 
    if ( in_array( $artist, $female_artist ) ) {
        
        $gender = "female"; 
    
        } elseif ( in_array( $artist, $fale_artist ) ) {
            $gender ="male";
        } else {
            $gender = "null";
        }
    }

 return $filename;
```

The part I am totally lose is how to use regular expression to assign the correct value into the filename variables ...

Can someone please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?P<C>C\d+)-(?P<S>S\d+)-(?P<Name>[^_]+)(?P<other>_[^.]+)?\.mp3
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/KwZe8N/1).

---

Broken down, this reads

```
(?P<C>C\d+)-       # C, followed by digits and "-"
(?P<S>S\d+)-       # S, followed by digits and "-"
(?P<Name>[^_].+)   # the name part, anything not an underscore
(?P<other>_[^.]+)? # optional part, anything not a dot
\.mp3              # ".mp3" literally
```

You see, the expression makes the assumption that names do not have underscores (e.g. `Jennifer_Lopez` will lead to unexpected results) and that the optional part does not involve dots.

---

In `PHP` this could be:

```
<?php

$files = ["C1-S1-Jason_slow.mp3", "C1-S25-Jenny_revision2.mp3", 
            "C2-S43-Jason.mp3", "C4-S99-Thomas_with_background_music.mp3",
            "C5-S80-Jennifer_Lopez.mp3"];

$regex = "~(?P<C>C\d+)-(?P<S>S\d+)-(?P<Name>[^_\n]+)(?P<other>_[^.]+)?\.mp3~";

$needle = "Jason";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $file, $match)) {
        if ($match["Name"] == $needle) {
            echo "Yes: {$match[0]}\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And would yield

```
Yes: C1-S1-Jason_slow.mp3
Yes: C2-S43-Jason.mp3
```

You can compare your needle(s) with `$match` which is an associative array with the correct values on each iteration. See [**a working demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/oUI8CR).

Comment: Hi Jan, truly appreciate your help. I am very new to regular expression, your answer helped a lot.

Comment: But how can I assign different portion of your regex into my variable? For example, do I use this code:  $artist_pattern =  (?P<Name>[^_].+); $artist = preg_match($artist_pattern, $filename, $match); ?>

Comment: @Atimmy: I updated the answer with some additional code. The point is to use an associative array within `preg_match(...)` and compare your needle(s).

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you again. Sorry maybe I wasn't being very clear in my questions. In the audio folder, I have hundreds of audio files, so I wouldn't be listing all of my files name in php. 

What I am hoping to do is that <?= get_audio_file("C1", "S25"); ?> 

would output "C1-S25-Jenny_revision2.mp3". (The php will search all the audio filename in the folder and find a matching file with filename start with "C1-S25"...

Comment: Each of my post has a custom field with the category and story_id information. so in my front-end template, I managed to setup $category and $story_id variable.

I am trying to have this function placed in my single cpt template page: <?= get_audio_file($category, $story_id) ?> and hoping it will yield the matching filename, so I can place that URL into the mp3 player

Comment: I did some search and looks like I have to use php built-in function glob() and regular expression together...

Comment: @Atimmy: No. But you need to have all files listed beforehand. To find all, either look them up and analyze them via regular expressions or use a database altogether. How should any algorithm guess which files are there or not? You need to have all files beforehand.

Comment: Can't I use glob to grab the file first and use regex to grab the particular string needed ?

Comment: @Atimmy: Of course you can but honestly I do not really see an advantage. You still need all filenames to search them. Whether you get the list via glob or any other directory function does not really make a difference.

Comment: In your code of example, can you kindly do another example where it only yield the voice-over artist name (ex. Jason, Jenny..etc) instead of the full filename? 

How can I only get this part using regex on filename?
(?P<Name>[^_].+)   # the name part, anything not an underscore